# CI Session not supported with php 5.4

Tags: php, codeigniter-3, session-variables

On Ci user guide say

PHP version 5.6 or newer is recommended.

It should work on 5.3.7 as well, but we strongly advise you NOT to run such old versions of PHP, because of potential security and performance issues, as well as missing features.

[image]

But I have php version 5.4 and CI version 3.1.6 and session is not working. $this->session->userdata(); is only providing

```
    Array
       (
         [__ci_last_regenerate] => 1546172950
       )
```

after page redirection.
But if i print the same thing just after storing it in session->set_userdata(), it provides everything I have stored in userdata as :

```
    $data = array(
                'admin_id' => $row->id,
                'adminusername' => $row->admin_user_name,
                'admin_type' => $row->admin_type,
                'no_of_time_login' => $row->no_of_time_login,
                'is_logged_in' => TRUE
            );

        $this->session->set_userdata($data);
        echo "<pre>";
        print_r($this->session->userdata());
        echo "</pre>";
        exit;

    Result : 
    Array
    (
        [__ci_last_regenerate] => 1546173253
        [admin_id] => 1
        [adminusername] => suzan
        [admin_type] => 1
        [no_of_time_login] => 87
        [is_logged_in] => 1
    )
```

And its working perfectly on my localhost and my test server with php 5.6. Is there any way to fix it, or should i downgrade the CI, or upgrade the php ?

Comment: What do you have in your /application/config/config.php for the sessions section?

Comment: @TimBrownlaw php version upgraded, problem solved.

Comment: That ole nugget ;) Glad to hear it - something to keep in mind. What version PHP did you upgrade to? I am running PHP 5.5.9 on this test box with no issues...

Comment: @TimBrownlaw I upgraded from 5.4 to 5.6.